# Comparing sets of independent sets with one another

Tags: machine-learning, anova, t-test, multivariate-analysis

This question is somewhat hard for me to articulate (I'm not extremely familiar with stats). My problem is this: I have a set of users, lets say User0-UserN. Each user has the potential to generate quantitive data sets X0-Xn. X is categorical and non-unique, such that the category Xa of User0 is equal to Xa of User1. Xn contains a set of numbers.

I would like to make comparisons between User0 and UserN based on a comparison between the data set Xa of User0 and Xa of UserN, Xb of User0 and Xb of UserN and so on.

My stats professor suggested using a ANOVA test, yet I don't see a good way to use this. I have also considered a T test and just comparing the results, but this doesn't seem very sound.

What would be a good way to perfect this analysis? The closest concept in the real world I can come to would be comparing fingerprints or perhaps faces, though I do not know how this is done either.

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide.

UPDATE#1: So far I'm considering using a t-test between each set I'm comparing. Perhaps then I will just calculate a percentage of the number of "Successful" comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called a "similarity function". Similarity functions are essentially different ways of determining how "close" or "far" two data points (Users in your case) are from each other.

There are a great number of different similarity functions that exist, each of which have areas they are appropriate for and areas they are not. A couple examples are [Pearson's correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) and [Goodman and Kruskal's lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman_and_Kruskal%27s_lambda). ANOVA or t-tests tests can also be used to define a similarity function, where the F or t statistic gives the dissimilarity between two columns. They aren't really designed for that, however.

In order to apply most common similarity measurements, you'll need to convert your data into tabular data. For your categorical sets, you can do this via a process known as "binarization". Each categorical level (that is, each individual value which can appear in your sets X) gets its own column. The value for a given user in each column is 1 if the user's set contains the level, and 0 otherwise. Each user thus becomes a row of your new table.

The numeric set will need a bit more thinking to turn into a set of columns, and what is appropriate will depend on the kind of information being represented by that set. You may want to find the mean, median, standard deviation, or other summary statistics on the number set and use those values as your columns.

This vectorization process is more or less what is done in image comparison. Each image is turned into a vector, with each pixel a column. The column values are determined by the color that pixel holds for each image.

Once you have your data in a tabular format, it is relatively simple to calculate correlation matrices relating each pair of users using any similarity function you desire to use.